# Extend Highcharts Export

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export

I need to set the resources object within the Highcharts exporting module's exportChart method but can't seem to overwrite it.

The export module source code is located at http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.src.js and the specific subsection of this that I am overwriting looks like this:

```
'use strict';
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = factory;
    } else {
        factory(Highcharts);
    }
}(function (Highcharts) {
    (function (H) {

        // create shortcuts
        var Chart = H.Chart,
            merge = H.merge,
            extend = H.extend;

        //... Removed extra code not needed for example
        extend(Chart.prototype, /** @lends Highcharts.Chart.prototype */ {
            exportChart: function (exportingOptions, chartOptions) {

                var svg = this.getSVGForExport(exportingOptions, chartOptions);

                // merge the options
                exportingOptions = merge(this.options.exporting, exportingOptions);

                // do the post
                H.post(exportingOptions.url, {
                    filename: exportingOptions.filename || 'chart',
                    type: exportingOptions.type,
                    // IE8 fails to post undefined correctly, so use 0
                    width: exportingOptions.width || 0,
                    scale: exportingOptions.scale,
                    svg: svg
                }, exportingOptions.formAttributes);

            }
            //... Removed extra code not needed for example
        });
        //... Removed extra code not needed for example

    }(Highcharts));
}));
```

To test the ability to overwrite the method I am using the following code:

```
(function (H) {
   var Chart = H.Chart,
       extend = H.extend;

   extend(Chart.prototype, /** @lends Highcharts.Chart.prototype */ {
       exportChart: function (exportingOptions, chartOptions) {
           alert('changed it');    
       }
   });  

}(Highcharts));
```

The alert never fires but instead the normal export is still happening.

I've created a JSFiddle showing this issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/j005v79j/

Can anyone tell me why the overwriting of this method isn't working?

Comment: The alert fires as expected on my machine. Which option do you click to launch exporting? (Download PNG / Download JPEG / ...)

Comment: You're right, I realized I was also loading https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js on my side which overwrote the export buttons to use a different method called exportChartLocal(). Thanks for pointing out that the fiddle was working. I must have been staring at the same problem too long and got missed this.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was also loading code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js on my side which was not in the fiddle. This script overwrote the export buttons to use a different method called exportChartLocal(). Since the buttons were now tied to a method that would never be called my alert was not firing.

I've removed the call to offline-exporting for now and will write overwrites into my code for this version at a later date.

Thanks to @Kamil for pointing out the issue.